# Assets 2.1.4 strange behaviour: "Could not upload the file ... "

Tags: assets, database, error, image, 2.7.0

- Assets is the only thirdparty module/filedtype installed.
- Native cache folder are 777.
- File upload directory is working and uploads images correctly.
- Assets shows no folder at all. But if I upload one image AFTER installing Assets the folder shows up.
- When trying to upload one image to the visible folder I get error message as follows: **"Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings."**
- The status bar shows full process is done but there is no images.
- When trying to update the button goes "blank" and no result is shown.
- Assets now has created two cache folders in "cache > assets tmp_storage" and they  are both 777. But no images ...

... ANYONE?

### Versions

- Assets 2.1.4
- EE 2.7.0
- PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8

Comment: After installing Assets, did you run the Index update process? There's a button called "update indexes" on the top right when in Assets.

Comment: Also, check your .htaccess file. Sometimes this can be an issue if you are removing index.php. Does the native file upload work to that directory?

Comment: What is the solution if this is a .htaccess issue? I'm able to upload via the native File Manager, but see "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings." when I use Assets. If I refresh the page, the file is in fact there.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue here with Expression Engine 2.7.2 and Assets 2.4.1

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Update your version of Assets to at least 2.2 as there was a fix for this per the changelog: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/changelog.html

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact problem.

I added 777 to:

> system > expressionengine > cache > assets

and

> system > expressionengine > cache > assets > thumbs